# Why i got fatal error / Jquery load + PHP GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

I have that code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#dirr").click(function(){
        $("section[name=files]").load('pages/files.php?' + $.param({dir: 2}););
    });
});
```

and that error on page:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in \pages\files.php on line 51
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?
if($_GET['dir'] == ""){
    echo '<form id="dirform" method="POST" action="?f=createdir">
            <label>Create directory:
            <input type="text" id="cdir" name="cdir" required>
            <input type="radio" name="dirpub" id="dirpub" value="1" checked>Public
            <input type="radio" name="dirpub" id="dirpub" value="0">Private
            <input type="submit" value="Create !">
            </label></form>';
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM directories WHERE id_dono=:iddono");
    $sth->bindParam(":iddono", $linha["id"]);
    $sth->execute();
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($row["public"] == 1){
            $status="Public";
        }else{
            $status="Private";
        }
            echo '<div id="dir" class="4u">
        <article class="item"><script>
$(function(){
    $("#dirr").click(function(){
        $("section[name=files]").load(\'pages/files.php?dir='.$row["id"].'#files\');
    });
});
</script>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="dirr" class="image full"><img src="'.$row["icon"].'" alt="" /></a>
            <header>
                <h3>'.$row["name"].' - '.$status.'</h3>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>'; 
    }
}
```

It's not complete already, i need that link working. i changed the

$("section[name=files]").load('pages/files.php?' + $.param({dir: 2}););

to:

$("section[name=files]").load(\'pages/files.php?dir='.$row["id"].'#files\');

Comment: what does `prepare()` function do?

Comment: Show us the code in files.php

Comment: You probably tried to connect to a database with mysqli or pdo, the connection failed, you failed to check for failure, and now are trying to use an invalid database handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
$.param({dir: 2});
```

to this:

```
$.param({dir: 2})
```

What I did was to drop the semicolon! =)

Comment: didn't worked, i changed to $("section[name=files]").load(\'pages/files.php?dir='.$row["id"].'#files\'); and the same error